# $f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ over $Z_2[x]$. What are the automorphisms of this field???

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

$f(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ over $Z_2[x]$ what are the automorphisms of this field???

---

**what is known**
the field $F=Z_2[x]/(f(x))$ has order of
$|F|=3^2=8$

letting $a$ be a zero rot of $f(x)$ in F

$$
\begin{aligned}
 F&=\{0,1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6\}
  \\&=\{0,1,a,a+1,a^2,a^2+a+1,a^2+1,a^2+a\}
\end{aligned}$$

if $a$ is a zero then $a^2,a^4$ are also zeros

so $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-a^2)(x-a^4)$$

---

Theorem1

$$[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n $$

th2
For each divisor $m$ of $n$, $FF(p^n)$ has a unique subfield of order $p^m$, moreover these are the only subfields of $GF(p^n)$

***I am not sure that helps  for the question being find all the automorphisms for the field but it's something***

**Attempt1**

so it would be something like $$ Z(a,a^2,a^4)$$

Taking a wild guess its $8$ the lcm??

**Attempt 2**

Möbius inversion formula

$p=3,n=2$ the divisors of $p$ are 3 and 1

$$ \psi (2)=\frac{1}{3}[\mu(1) (3)^3+ \mu(3) (3)^1] = 
\frac{1}{3}[ (3)^3- (3)^1]=27-3=24$$

Comment: another way would be to make it into a symmetric group Im not sure how to do here. In lang pg 274, argues that $X^5-x-1$ over Z. reducing mod 5 shows that this polynomial is irreducible and reducing mod2 gives irreducible factors $ (x^2+X+1)(x^3+x^2+1) $ (mod 2). hence the galois group over the rationals contains  a 5 cyle and a product of a 2 and 3 cycle.  ....  Thus the galois group of $X^5-X-1$ is $S_5$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Your attempt 1 is the right track. Consider the *Frobenius homomorphism* of the field  $F$, $\operatorname{Fr}\colon x\longmapsto x^2$. Iterating this homomorphism, you obtaid the $3$ roots of the polynomial $x^3+x+1$, and as $F$ is a simple extension of $\mathbf F_2$, this means the polynomial splits in $F$.

Therefore, since automorphisms of a simple extension are entirely determined by the image of its primitive element, its Galois group is generated by $\operatorname{Fr}$. You can easily check that $\operatorname{Fr}^3=\operatorname{Id_F}$, so the Galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$.